# Unable to retrieve record using DateTime.Now in EntityFramework 6.1 with Code First approach

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I was writing some tests to checking whether the validation procedures work as expected and encountered very peculiar behaviour.

Within the test method:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
using(CustomDbContext db = new CustomDbContext())
{
    Object1 o1 = new Object1();
    o1.CompletedOn = now;
    db.Object1s.Add(o1);
    db.SaveChanges();

    var query = from obj in db.Object1s
                where obj.CompletedOn == now
                select obj;

    Assert.AreNotEqual(query.Count(), 0);
}
```

The moment I did that:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
using(CustomDbContext db = new CustomDbContext())
{
    Object1 o1 = new Object1();
    o1.CompletedOn = now;
    db.Object1s.Add(o1);
    db.SaveChanges();


    DateTime now2 = now.AddSeconds(-1);
    var query = from obj in db.Object1s
                where obj.CompletedOn > now2
                select obj;

    Assert.AreNotEqual(query.Count(), 0);
}
```

It worked.

Under normal circumstances I would think that the `now` holds the reference to `DataTime.Now`, hence the time would change. However, the debugger indicates this isn't the case. The times passed in both cases are identical and the result **is stored in the database**.

I am using Code First Approach to build the database this is what the Object1:

```
class Object1
{
    [Key]
    public int Object1ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CompletedOn { get; set; }
}
```

I am using SQL Server as my database. Has this something to do with it?

The values can be stored in SQL Server looks like this one: 2014-09-23 13:14:18.157

Comment: DateTime and consequently DateTime.Now() is not reference based, it is a value based struct - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: where obj.CompletedOn > now2

Comment: @MikeMiller Yeah I figured that out, this is why I am asking the question. Both times should be identical, but I can't retrieve the result from the database.

Comment: What type is your `CompletedOn` column in the database? If it's `datetime`, that has less precision than a .NET `DateTime` value, so storing it in a database will cause rounding.

Comment: @Tanner Well, I agree with you: that would be the case if we had a reference, but as MikeMiller said: "it is a value based struct". So I guess it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: What is the value of Query.Count, what values have you got in db.Object1s already?

Comment: @hvd Yeah... I was thinking this has something to do with the precision of data, but then again you use exactly the same data to store and retrieve i.e. if you store value and it doesn't like milliseconds it will chop them and I would image the same would happen if you try to retrieve the result. Though, admittedly this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: You can try Compare method.

But still, DateTime in fact holds ticks. In my opinion, comparing time to have EXACTLY the same tick value is a bit ... not smart :)

I mean, they have to be exactly the same. Try something like like (obj.CompletedOn.Substract(now) < DateTime(100)) or whatever value you find ok

Comment: @MikeMiller the value for the query.Count() in the first code is 0, in the second is 1. I've tracked the problem down. There is exactly 1 more millisecond stored in the SQL Server compared to what is given in obj.CompletedOn... (SQL Server: 453, DateTime: 452). So I assume there must be some rounding involved...

Comment: @DawidO Perhaps it's easier to use a `numeric` type when explaining. Suppose you've got a `numeric(18,1)` data type mapped to a .NET `decimal` property. You store `1.01m`, and then select records where that property exactly equals that value. You also won't get anything back. In that case, it's obvious: you don't have any records where the stored value equals `1.01m`, because that value *cannot* be stored in any record. Selection doesn't convert `1.01m` to the type of the field. It's really the same problem here. To find the record, you'd need to round `1.01m` to `1.0m` in your code too.

Comment: @DawidO Or, as an obvious alternative, use a data type capable of exactly storing the value you're attempting to store. But you haven't shown how it's stored in the database.

Comment: @hvd Yeah... I do get the point with rounding, the same thing happens with floats. It all depends how they are stored. There is some rounding involved, because there is of fluctuation -/+10 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Profiler to see what the specific date time is being sent through and you'll see the difference between the stored value and parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

The code above doesn't work because for some unknown reason, it seems that there is about +/-10 ms different between the stored value in the database and what is given as the parameter in the `DateTime`.

So rather then using:

```
DateTime now2 = now.AddSeconds(-1);
```

I can use:

```
DateTime now2 = now.AddMilliseconds(-10);
```